# The Hopf conjecture for products and slight modification

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Perhaps this post won't get too much attention, and I apologize if this is deeply charged with a self perspective more than general facts.

I would like to know why do people believe that the standard Hopf conjecture for $S^2\times S^2$ is true. I have a few knowledge about the recent works on the literature, in particular the works of Bettiol-Mendes, and which concerns the generalized Hopf conjecture

> $M\times N$ does not admit admit a metric with positive sectional curvature,

the work of Lee Kennard (although I must admit I am not quite familiar with this).

Still, I haven't understood yet the plausibility of the Hopf conjecture for $S^2\times S^2$. It is probably more a deep flaw on my background than anything else. However, although I can't justify too much, apart from my own tries on these conjectures, that perhaps this conjecture may be not true. Instead, what if the following was true:

> Let $(M,g)$, $(N,h)$ closed Riemannian manifolds with positive sectional curvature. Then, $M\times N$ admits a metric of positive sectional curvature if, and only if, $\chi(M\times N) > 0$.

Note that this conjecture, if true, asserts that $M^{2n}\times M^{2m+1}$ would not care a metric of positive sectional curvature, but $S^2\times S^2$ may be.

This conjecture is false provided $M$ or $N$ do not care a metric of positive sectional curvature (for example, there are exotic spheres that do not bound spin manifolds that don't even admit a metric of positive scalar curvature).

I haven't seen this last conjecture on literature, but it relates two of the known Hopf conjectures, and I would like to know: what do you think about the plausibility of it? Is there more reason to believe in it than the standard Hopf conjecture for spheres?

Comment: I wouldn’t say that it’s believed to be true. There have been serious efforts to construct a counterexample. What is perhaps surprising is how hard this turns out to be.